# Undefined values while using multiple ngFor in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I am using multiple ngFor loops in Angular. I want to select Month and Year range. So there are 4 drop down menus (Month from, Year from, Month to, Year to). The problem is that I have tried using multiple ngFor loops before too in different stages, but same issue occurs. 1 ngFor loop works fine in HTML, but using multiple ngFor loops, only 1 works fine while the rest are having undefined values. Please have a look, Thankyou.

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <select name="monthf" id="monthf" [(ngModel)]="monthf" class="form-control" placeholder="monthf" >
    <option [value]="month" *ngFor="let month of months">{{month}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>selected: {{monthf}}</p>

  <select name="yearf" id="yearf" [(ngModel)]="yearf" class="form-control" placeholder="yearf" >
    <option [value]="yearf" *ngFor="let year of years">{{year}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>selected: {{yearf}}</p>
 
  <select name="montht" id="montht" [(ngModel)]="montht" class="form-control" placeholder="montht" >
    <option [value]="montht" *ngFor="let month of months">{{month}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>selected: {{montht}}</p>

  <select name="yeart" id="yeart" [(ngModel)]="yeart" class="form-control" placeholder="yeart" >
    <option [value]="yeart" *ngFor="let year of years">{{year}}</option>
  </select>

  <p>selected: {{yeart}}</p>
</div>
```

Component.ts code(only these values are being used from the `.ts` file that is why I only mentioned these values):

```
months:string[]=['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];
years:number[]=Array.from(Array(50)).map((_, i) => 2000 + i);//generate 100 years from 2000 to 2100
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please add your .ts-file as well

Comment: You have a typo in your options' value property. The `[value]` binding should contain the symbol that you defined in your for loop. The first one is the only one that does not have a typo, the remaining 3 have an extra character at the end (either _f_ or _t_). Remove those and check again.